# Reusing a Class - Will Unused IBOutlets Cause a Crash

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet

Let's say I have a Storyboard ViewController with 10 labels, each is connected to its viewControllerClass via IBOutlet.

Now I make a NEW ViewController that is extremely similar. However, it only has 9 labels. Those nine labels should be handled by the code in the same way the 9 labels in the original VC are handled.

Can I just make the new ViewController's class the same class as the original if I make sure that in the code the 10th label is safely unwrapped? Or does every IBOutlet in the code need to have a connection in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly safe to have IBOutlets that have not been connected in a storyboard or xib. The only side effect is that these outlets will be nil.

Comment: Also note that if you use an IBOutlet that is nil, you will receive a fatal crash.

Comment: A nil variable does not necessarily mean a crash. It may, but depends on the situation. It depends what you do with nil such as adding it to an NSArray in objetive-c or or the swift unwrapping method used. There are many more specific examples but in the general case you can't say that nil variables always lead to a crash.